# RIGHT-TO-LEFT char \u200f causing problems in python

Tags: python, utf-8, right-to-left

I am reading a web page using urllib which is in utf-8 charset and includes the RIGHT-TO-LEFT charecter 
http://www.charbase.com/200f-unicode-right-to-left-mark

but when I try to write all of that into a UTF-8 based text file

```
with codecs.open("results.html","w","utf-8") as outFile:
    outFile.write(htmlResults) 
    outFile.close()
```

I get the 
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 264: ordinal not in range(128)" 
error message ....

how do I fix that ?

Comment: are you sure that's the code your getting an exception from? (the exception is about `decode` and your code does `encode`...)

Comment: You fix it by making sure the strings you write to the file (i.e. `htmlResults`) are Unicode strings. Sounds like they aren't.

Comment: sorry guys I must have copied one of my old tests code to here, now edit the question to show my latest code that makes the error

Comment: What is the type of `htmlResults`?

Comment: when I print the web page html text to the console (python IDLE) it shows fine as a utf-8 code, I have also checked the response headers which shows that the page uses UTF-8

Comment: br = mechanize.Browser()

htmlResults = br.open("http://www.website.com").read()

Comment: What does `print type(htmlResults)` output? (if you have utf-8 text you cannot encode it again -- perhaps you're confused about utf-8 vs Unicode?)

Comment: <type 'str'> this is the output

Comment: my problem is that if I write the htmlResults to the file using the standard open (no encoding choice) the file will be written in ANSI encoding which results in webbrowsers not being able to correctly detect the encoding (to utf-8), I need the file saved in UTF-8 so that web browsers will be able to correctly detect and view the web page in utf-8

Comment: ANSI isn't an encoding...

Answer (score 0):

If `htmlResults` is of type `str` then you need to figure out what encoding it is in if you're going to decode it to Unicode (only Unicode can be encoded). E.g. if `htmlResults` is encoded as iso-8859-1 (i.e. latin-1), then

```
tmp = htmlResults.decode('iso-8859-1')
```

would create a Unicode string in tmp which you could then write to a file:

```
with codecs.open("results.html","w","utf-8") as outFile:
    tmp = htmlResults.decode('iso-8859-1')
    outFile.write(tmp)
```

if `htmlResults` is encoded as utf-8 then you do not need to do any decoding/encoding:

```
with open('results.html', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(htmlResults)
```

(the with statement will close the file for you).

This is not related to what browsers interpret the file as however, that is determined by the `Content-Type` that the web server is serving the file as, along with associated meta tags. E.g. if the file is html5 you ought to have this near the top of the head tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```